# Doctrine 2 - MySql : multiples 'BASE TABLE' queries added to every views

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Do you know why every views of my Symfony 4.4.25 website using Doctrine ORM 2.9.3 add between 3 and 10 queries like this:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

The database is MySQL version 5.7

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with packages that "insulate" the user from MySQL.  They get sloppy about using lots of extra, seemingly unnecessary, information-gathering queries.

Comment: Not sure enough to post it as an answer but it might have something to do with misconfigured metadata cache, so it queries for metadata every time. Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: @FilipHalaxa thanks for the link, but after trying all possible possibilities, I still have the extra queries. Weird.

Comment: Stupid question, but don't you run migrations on every request by accident?

Comment: @FilipHalaxa no, but thanks for your reflexion

Comment: What this gives you? `var_dump(get_class($entityManager->getConfiguration()->getMetadataCache()));`

Comment: @FilipHalaxa `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Sounds like a bug, should be fix in  doctrine migration bundle version 3.2 https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/421

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue from a recent symfony 4.4 install, and fix it by removing the following parameter from `doctrine_migrations.yaml`:

```
enable_profiler: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Comment: Yes, it is a bug at this time, will be merged in the next release : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/421

Comment: But your workaround is correct, the feature can be deactivated with this new param